# GTK basics : learning from sources

Tags: gtk

I am new at programming Gtk gnome linux C application, and I am trying to learn from some source reagind and online gnome documentation but I can't do it because this is in my opinion very poor and bad. I have a problem understanding this following source: after creating a GObject of GApplication type, how can this main function call other parts of programs? (This is from gedit source) I learnt that GApplication doesn't include any pointer to some code.

```
/*
 * gedit.c
 * This file is part of gedit
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2005 - Paolo Maggi
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include <config.h>
#endif

#include "gedit-app.h"
#ifdef OS_OSX
#include "gedit-app-osx.h"
#else
#ifdef G_OS_WIN32
#include "gedit-app-win32.h"
#else
#include "gedit-app-x11.h"
#endif
#endif

#include <glib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <libintl.h>

#include "gedit-dirs.h"
#include "gedit-debug.h"

#ifdef G_OS_WIN32
#include <gmodule.h>
static GModule *libgedit_dll = NULL;

/* This code must live in gedit.exe, not in libgedit.dll, since the whole
 * point is to find and load libgedit.dll.
 */
static gboolean
gedit_w32_load_private_dll (void)
{
    gchar *dllpath;
    gchar *prefix;

    prefix = g_win32_get_package_installation_directory_of_module (NULL);

    if (prefix != NULL)
    {
        /* Instead of g_module_open () it may be possible to do any of the
         * following:
         * A) Change PATH to "${dllpath}/lib/gedit;$PATH"
         * B) Call SetDllDirectory ("${dllpath}/lib/gedit")
         * C) Call AddDllDirectory ("${dllpath}/lib/gedit")
         * But since we only have one library, and its name is known, may as well
         * use gmodule.
         */
        dllpath = g_build_filename (prefix, "lib", "gedit", "libgedit.dll", NULL);
        g_free (prefix);

        libgedit_dll = g_module_open (dllpath, 0);
        if (libgedit_dll == NULL)
        {
            g_printerr ("Failed to load '%s': %s\n",
                        dllpath, g_module_error ());
        }

        g_free (dllpath);
    }

    if (libgedit_dll == NULL)
    {
        libgedit_dll = g_module_open ("libgedit.dll", 0);
        if (libgedit_dll == NULL)
        {
            g_printerr ("Failed to load 'libgedit.dll': %s\n",
                        g_module_error ());
        }
    }

    return (libgedit_dll != NULL);
}

static void
gedit_w32_unload_private_dll (void)
{
    if (libgedit_dll)
    {
        g_module_close (libgedit_dll);
        libgedit_dll = NULL;
    }
}
#endif

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GType type;
    GeditApp *app;
    gint status;
    const gchar *dir;

#ifdef OS_OSX
    type = GEDIT_TYPE_APP_OSX;
#else
#ifdef G_OS_WIN32
    if (!gedit_w32_load_private_dll ())
    {
        return 1;
    }

    type = GEDIT_TYPE_APP_WIN32;
#else
    type = GEDIT_TYPE_APP_X11;
#endif
#endif

    /* NOTE: we should not make any calls to the gedit api before the
     * private library is loaded */
    gedit_dirs_init ();

    /* Setup locale/gettext */
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "");

    dir = gedit_dirs_get_gedit_locale_dir ();
    bindtextdomain (GETTEXT_PACKAGE, dir);

    bind_textdomain_codeset (GETTEXT_PACKAGE, "UTF-8");
    textdomain (GETTEXT_PACKAGE);

    app = g_object_new (type,
                        "application-id", "org.gnome.gedit",
                        "flags", G_APPLICATION_HANDLES_COMMAND_LINE | G_APPLICATION_HANDLES_OPEN,
                        NULL);

    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);

    /* Break reference cycles caused by the PeasExtensionSet
     * for GeditAppActivatable which holds a ref on the GeditApp
     */
    g_object_run_dispose (G_OBJECT (app));

    g_object_add_weak_pointer (G_OBJECT (app), (gpointer *) &app);
    g_object_unref (app);

    if (app != NULL)
    {
        gedit_debug_message (DEBUG_APP, "Leaking with %i refs",
                             G_OBJECT (app)->ref_count);
    }

#ifdef G_OS_WIN32
    gedit_w32_unload_private_dll ();
#endif

    return status;
}

/* ex:set ts=8 noet: */
```

Comment: main function doesn't need to call any other parts of the program -- `g_application_run()` starts the mainloop and the mainloop will invoke everything else that needs to run (timers, signal handlers, etc). The GApplication implementation (in your example probably GeditAppX11) would be your starting point to see what exactly the mainloop might invoke.

Comment: Is GApplication library that find the remaining program? Oh, I don't knew! But please tell me how it works

Comment: Not sure what you mean, "find the remaining program" -- you can see how it includes gedit-app-x11.h (assuming X11): that will define a GeditAppX11 class that gets instantiated in the g_object_new() line. GeditAppX11 will probably then include and use lots of other classes.

Comment: Oh ... i didn't see it! Excuse me for question !